# move one element after another element in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that contains the following elements:
`"A", "B", "C", "D"`
I want to move `"A"` after `"C"` to have the following order:
`"B", "C", "A", "D"`
I use this code:

```
 int sourceIndex = arrayList.indexOf("A");
 int destIndex = arrayList.indexOf("C");
 arrayList.add(destIndex, "A");
 arrayList.remove(sourceIndex);
```

the result of the above code looks like this:
`"B", "A", "C", "D"`
**What is the best way to move one element after another element?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all, I finally used this code:

```
 public static void moveElementAfter(ArrayList<String> arrayList,String src, String dst) {
    int sourceIndex = arrayList.indexOf(src);
    int destIndex = arrayList.indexOf(dst);
    // copy source element after destination
    arrayList.add(destIndex + 1, src);

    if (sourceIndex < destIndex) {
        // * the source element is moved forward in the array list
        // remove the source element
        arrayList.remove(sourceIndex);
    } else {
        // * the source element is moved backward in the array list
        // remove the source element
        int sourceLastIndex = arrayList.lastIndexOf(src);
        arrayList.remove(sourceLastIndex);
    }// end if
    System.out.println(arrayList);
}// end method
```

**Demo**

```
System.out.println("move A after C");
ArrayList<String> arrayList1  = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
moveElementAfter(arrayList1, "A", "C");

System.out.println("move C after A");
ArrayList<String> arrayList2  = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
moveElementAfter(arrayList2, "C", "A");
```

**Output**

```
[B, C, A, D]
[A, C, B, D]
```

Answer (score 4):

Swap the order of adding and deleting the elements to make it work. Note that whenever you remove an element from an `ArrayList`, all the indices after that position get decreased by one place; in other words, all the elements after that position get shifted to the left (or towards the beginning) by one position.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));

        int sourceIndex = list.indexOf("A");
        int destIndex = list.indexOf("C");
        
        list.remove(sourceIndex);
        list.add(destIndex, "A");
        
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[B, C, A, D]
```

There can be many other ways to do it e.g.

**Rotate and swap:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");

        Collections.rotate(list, 3);
        System.out.println(list);

        Collections.swap(list, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[B, C, D, A]
[B, C, A, D]
```

**Just swap:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
        
        Collections.swap(list, 0, 1);
        System.out.println(list);
        
        Collections.swap(list, 1, 2);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[B, A, C, D]
[B, C, A, D]
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case you can modify your initial `"A", "B", "C", "D"` list to the `"B", "C", "A", "D"` list  with `arrayList.add(destIndex + 1, "A")` instead of `arrayList.add(destIndex, "A")` like below:

```
int sourceIndex = arrayList.indexOf("A");
int destIndex = arrayList.indexOf("C");
arrayList.add(destIndex + 1, "A");
arrayList.remove(sourceIndex);
```

Be aware that [`List:add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) and [`List:remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()), so this code cannot be applied to every scenario.